# Create random string that includes spaces (one space between characters), and first character is not a space

Tags: c#

I have a method that creates a random string that includes spaces with a user-specified length. The problem is, is that sometimes it inserts spaces at the beginning of the string, and it creates consecutive spaces. How do I combat this so my string never has any spaces in the first character but still can have spaces at other indexes (non-consecutive). Keep in mind that I want to be exact with the sizeOfString parameter, so I need the end result to still be a user-specified amount of characters

This is my method:

```
    public static string CreateRandomString(int sizeOfString)
    {
        const string chars = "A b  C  D  e  F  g  H  I  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ";

        var random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, sizeOfString)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? I can think of two really obvious ways of doing it, right off the top of my head.

Comment: Use `TrimStart()` - `return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, sizeOfString).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).TrimStart().ToArray();`

Comment: Problem with just `TrimStart` is that then he might have a string shorter than requested by `sizeOfString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an infinite sequence of random chars, skip while they are spaces and then take the number of characters you want.

If you declare a new random within your function, then if you call the function too frequently your random strings get repeated.

Also, the frequency of spaces is very high as more than half of your characters are spaces, you could use `chars = " AbCDeFgHI12345678"` to alleviate this.

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public static string CreateRandomString(int sizeOfString)
{
    const string chars = "A b  C  D  e  F  g  H  I  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  ";

    var randomChars =
        InitInfinite(() => chars[random.Next(chars.Length)])
            .SkipWhile(c => c == ' ')
            .Take(sizeOfString);

    return new string(randomChars.ToArray());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> InitInfinite<T>(Func<T> selector)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return selector();
    }
}
```

Edit - And here's version 2 (final version):

```
public static string CreateRandomSentence(int sizeOfString)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (sb.Length < sizeOfString)
    {
        int wordLength = random.Next(8) + 1;
        sb.Append(CreateRandomString(wordLength)).Append(" ");
    }

    sb.Length = sizeOfString;

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string CreateRandomString(int sizeOfString)
{
    const string chars = "AbCDeFgHI12345678";

    var randomChars =
        InitInfinite(() => chars[random.Next(chars.Length)])
            .SkipWhile(c => c == ' ')
            .Take(sizeOfString);

    return new string(randomChars.ToArray());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> InitInfinite<T>(Func<T> selector)
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return selector();
    }
}

private static Random random = new Random();
```

Comment: You could use `String.Join` to be even more LINQy :) (I guess would be a bit slower than string from char array)

Comment: So would this still include spaces at less frequency (except for the first character)?

Comment: Yes, if you use `"A b  C  D  e  F  g  H  I  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  "` then each character will be a space 33 times out of 50 (66%).  If you use  `" AbCDeFgHI12345678"` then it will be a space only 2% of the time

Comment: This worked. Can you refactor this so that there are non-consecutive spaces in the returned string? I have edited my original post to include this question

Comment: I would have to question why you need spaces in the string.  If you really do, then you should probably generate _words_ of random length, then use `String.Join(" ", words)` to combine them into a _sentence_.

Comment: I am automating a test for some text boxes. One textbox only allows a maximum of 10 characters, another a maximum of 50. So I need the sizeOfString parameter. I dont think generating words with string.join can satisfy this under maximum requirement